# Making Wordpress-built website mobile friendly

Tags: plugins, mobile

I have a website that is built with `WordPress` but hosted on GoDaddy. I need to make it more mobile-friendly. I installed `WPTouch` and the `WordPress-Mobile Pack` to do so. However, I find that even after installing the plugins and re-installing the website on `GoDaddy`, the site remains mobile-unfriendly. Writing to GoDaddy support did not help much either since I was redirected to WordPress support. My question(s):

1. How do I make a WordPress website that is hosted by GoDaddy mobile compatible?
2. How do I activate plugins like WPTouch on GoDaddy?

Comment: Please improve your question, see [ask], btw hosting service related question are off topic, see [On topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I asked this question here to see if other people have been facing similar kinds of problems with WP plugins and hosting service providers. I have gone through the links you mentioned, and I feel that this question is valid, especially since it relates to plugins. If you do not think it so, please vote to close. If this question is closed, I will take it elsewhere.

Comment: Sure, maybe you are right and I'm wrong.

Comment: Although you've mentioned GoDaddy several times, your web host really has nothing to do with this question.  Try removing all references to GoDaddy in your question.

Comment: @BenMiller: The reason why I asked about GoDaddy was in reference to a post suggesting cross-site scripting vulnerabilities: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6745/crosssite-scripting-vulnerability-in-wptouch-plugin-19194-and-1920

Comment: @Sriram That post is a security advisory about a specific version of WPTouch that is not the current version.  It has nothing to do with GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1):

To make your WordPress site more mobile-friendly, your easiest choices are to install either a plugin or a theme that is mobile-friendly.  I don't have any specific recommendations for you (and asking for recommendations is off-topic on this site), but there are lots of options to choose from.

Don't run more than one "mobile" plugin or theme at a time, as they will likely interfere with each other.

It sounds like you've already chosen the WPTouch plugin.  If this is installed properly, you should notice a difference when you visit your site on a mobile device.

To check that the plugin is installed and activated:

Click on Plugins, Then click on the "All" link at the top of the Plugins page.  If you find "WPTouch" listed, then you've already got the plugin installed.  If you see an "Activate" link for the plugin, then the plugin is deactivated.  Click on the "Activate" link to activate it.  If you see a "Deactivate" link for this plugin, then it is already activated.

If you visit your site on a mobile device and WPTouch is activated, you'll see a slider button at the bottom of your page that the user can use to turn the mobile theme On or Off.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Themes. I use a theme generator which explicitly supports mobile-friendly "flow-layouts" and it looks great.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben. I was experimenting with different plugins and notice that `WordPress Mobile Pack` is currently active. Despite that, the website does not display correctly using Opera Mini or Opera Mobile on Android (the site is: www.knowthelaw.in).

Comment: I have not yet decided what plugin I will go with.. but at this point, I will go with one that works.

Answer (score 0):

if you have CSS knowledge you will achieve the goal in minutes by this way

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px){

//your CSS goes here

}
```

this CSS will only applied to any devices use this width you can also repeated this with diffrent width

Hope this help